# Implementing acts_as_saveable gem to favorite and unfavorite map markers and to generate a list of favorites - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-5, gmaps4rails

I am trying to implement the following gem into my project https://github.com/aliibrahim/Favorite-Lists . The example lists a current user as being able to favorite and unfavorite. My goal is to have a visitor who does not have to be logged in to favorite a map marker and unfavorite. From the favorites I want them to be saved and for a list of favorite map markers to be generated. So far this is what I have in my code in what I am testing starting with the view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!--Basic Table-->
                    <div class="panel panel-green margin-bottom-40">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <div class = "name"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="thumbnail-img">
                                    <div class="overflow-hidden">
                                    <%= image_tag 'creative/main/img3.jpg', :class => 'img-responsive' %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <button class="btn-u btn-u-lg rounded-4x btn-u-green" type="button"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Check Availability</button>
                            <button class="btn-u btn-u-lg rounded-4x btn-u-green" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add to Favorites</button>

    **<%= form_tag(controller: "maps", action: "favorite", method: "post")%>
      <%= submit_tag "Favorite"%>**

                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table paneltb">


                        </table>

                    </div>
                    <!--End Basic Table-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my model:

```
class Map < ApplicationRecord

    include PgSearch
    pg_search_scope :search, against: [:number, :tab_id, :zip_postal, :city]
    acts_as_saveable
      attr_accessor :file


    def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      map = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
      map.attributes = row.to_hash
      map.save!
    end
  end

end
```

And lastly this is my controller:

```
class MapsController < ApplicationController
  def index

      @maps = Map.all
      @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@maps) do |map, marker|
      marker.lat map.latitude
      marker.lng map.longitude
       marker.json({:id => map.id,
            :number => map.number,
            :tab_id => map.tab_id,
            :face => map.face,
            :street => map.street_,
            :street_1 => map.street_1,
            :position => map.position,
            :street_2 => map.street_2,
            :side_corner => map.side_corner,
            :city => map.city,
            :zip_postal => map.zip_postal,
            :latitude => map.latitude,
            :longitude => map.longitude
                  })     

    end
  end

  def favorite 
    @map = Map.new(:number => 'Favorite Site')
    @map.save
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:success] = "favorited"
  end

  def unfavorite
    @maps.unsave
    map.save
    redirect_to :back
    flash[:success] = "unfavorited"
  end

  def import
    Map.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to authors_posts_path, notice: "Locations Imported!"
  end

  def show
   @maps = Map.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

When I click on the favorite button in my modal on my map it goes through but I am unsure where. Here is what it looks like in the terminal:

```
Started POST "/favorite?method=post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-16 17:28:41 -0700
Processing by MapsController#favorite as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WxMK/PsUSrd35UssF6CviTfcPoHajRkJaxnb5zZUAWFUvxHgjY/czzxwRpyp+vPMLjiDnBbSJtfCRdCNhGuSvw==", "commit"=>"Favorite", "method"=>"post"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "maps" ("number", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["number", "Favorite Site"], ["created_at", 2017-07-17 00:28:41 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-07-17 00:28:41 UTC]]
   (32.5ms)  COMMIT
DEPRECATION WARNING: `redirect_to :back` is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1. Please use `redirect_back(fallback_location: fallback_location)` where `fallback_location` represents the location to use if the request has no HTTP referer information. (called from favorite at /home/krav/Desktop/martin_outdoor_media/app/controllers/maps_controller.rb:29)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/maps
Completed 302 Found in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 33.0ms)
```

Here is a screenshot of what the modal looks like [image: modal]

Answer (score 0):

I would comment, but I'm short 5 rep points. If we find the solution, I'll edit this answer to reflect it.

> When I click on the favorite button in my modal on my map it goes
>   through but I am unsure where.

I assume from this statement that you're looking for the table in which the data was saved, or the route/controller action that intercepted the data. Am I correct?

Comment: That is part of it yes.